# Backspace press detection

Tags: delphi, keypress

Is there a possibility for detection backspace key pressing (like an event) only while a cursor is over Timage component? This shortcut has to trigger dedicated image-processing related to TImage.

Comment: What if the focus control accepts input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just enable/disable they key-pressing detection event when the mouse enters or leaves the image (OnMouseEnter, OnMouseLeave).

You just need to have a BackDetection function (compatible with TKeyEvent) on your Form :

```
procedure MyForm.BackDetection(Sender: TObject; var Key: word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_BACK then begin
    ... 
    ... Your image-processing code
    ...
  end;   
end;
```

This does require that `KeyPreview` is `True`.

Then you just set this event, or disable it, when the mouse enter or leaves your image.

```
procedure MyForm.MyImageOnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OnKeyPress := BackDetection;
end;

procedure MyForm.MyImageOnMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OnKeyPress := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Alternatively, the key event could always be set and just check where the mouse is.